# How to trigger when TextEdit value changed?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I tried this:

```
houseField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), s, 15000).show();
        }
    });
```

But event triggered after each symbol inserted but I dont want that..

I need to trigger event when user leaves textedit and text is changed, becouse i will do query to google maps api. I can't do query after each character entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried onFocusChanged()

```
 yourTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
      if(hasFocus)
      {
        //do your logic here
      }
    }
 }
```

The other option is to use onTextChanged to start a timer which checks to delay the process and reset if another key stroke happens.  This approach may be more suitable to your application but is trickier to implement

**EDIT**

Alternatively you can override `boolean View.onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` and capture the enter key ( but you will also need to think about the user tapping the back key to dismiss keyboard).

Comment: It's not in the code above, but I guess this assumes the hasChanged is set in the onTextChanged from your TextWatcher.

Comment: oops that should be hasFocus ... changed it, but yeah you could do that, use onChanged to say `hasChanged=true` ... a serendipitous slip

Comment: Thanks will try with onFocusChange and timer should do that job

Comment: I think using a combination of hasChanged from onTextChanged in TextWatcher would be a pretty combo - consider in onFocusChange..
`if (!hasFocus && hasChanged)`

Answer (score 0):

```
use 
String sChange ="";
boolean change=false;
    @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             String new=s.toString();
             if(!sChange.equalsIgnoreCase(new))
            {
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), sChange, 15000).show();
                change=true;
            }
            else
             change=false;
           }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
              sChange=s;
        }

yourTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
  if(hasChanged)
  {
if(change)
//google logic

  }
}
```

}

Comment: Man, are you really Andy Rubin?